# Laravel form actions leads to undefined route

Tags: laravel

Form actions always confused me as it seemed very simple just to specify the controller however, every time I use it I always get `Route [Controller@method] not defined`. So I always go and manually make the route then use a url for my forms.

I currently have a route set up as `Route::controller('handle/events', 'EventsController')` and I'm trying to call the method `postAdd` from a form like:

`{{ Form::open(['action' => 'EventsController@postAdd']) }}`

instead of using
`['url' => 'handle/events/add']` which is perfectly acceptable given that this is a RESTful route.

When I use the action, Laravel throws `Route [EventsController@postAdd] not defined.`. The method `postAdd` in the EventsController also accepts a parameter which I would like to pass in the form.

In the controller, the method is

```
public function postAdd($staff = false) {

    var_dump($staff); // Always false

}
```

and once again I thought it would be as simple as:

`{{ Form::open(['url' => 'handle/events/add'], true) }}` however it did not change the value of `$staff`.

**Recap**

1. I would like to change my forms to point to controller methods rather than urls.
2. I would like to pass a parameter with my forms.

Answer (score 1):

First Problem can be solved by naming your routes.

```
For example: Route::post('handle/events/add',['as' => 'handle.event.add',  'uses' => 'EventsController@addMethod']);
```

Then in your form you can do something like this

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'handle.event.add', 'method' =>'POST'))}}
```

Now your form will  use EventsController@addMethod

Docs [named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes)

If you want to pass a parameter to the controller method you can define it in your route

`Route::get('handle/{event}',['as' => 'handle.event.add',  'uses' => 'EventsController@addMethod'])`

Now your addMethod expects a paramter.